# Re-assigning a new model in MVVM -> does not update child collection view models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, model-binding

I have a root Model ~ PropertyPortfolio ~ which I save/load from an XML file. It contains a child collection of Property objects.

When I load the application I load this object into a PropertyPortfolioService. The model uses INotifyPropertyChanged, so does the service - so I've got that covered.

I have a child view which displays a child collection of Property objects in a grid. Binding works fine.

The problem I have is this:

When I open a new PropertyPortfolio from a file I re-assign the PropertyPortfolio object in the service:

```
this.PropertyPortfolio = loadedPropertyPortfolio;
```

The child view/viewmodel does not update.

The solution I currently have is to load the new portfolio and recreate child objects, like this:

```
PropertyPortfolio loadedPropertyPortfolio = /* Code to load new portfolio from XML */;

this.PropertyPortfolio.Properties.Clear();

foreach (var property in loadedPropertyPortfolio.Properties)
{
    this.PropertyPortfolio.Properties.Add(property);
}
```

I'm looking for a better solution.

I hope that's descriptive enough?

---

Further information - The problem is with the PropertyViewModel (which contains a Property model object plus IsSelected logic).

This is the VM for an individual Property (for each Property in the collection):

public class PropertyViewModel
{
    public Property Property
    {
        get { return this.property; }
    }

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return this.isSelected; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref this.isSelected, value, () => IsSelected);
    }
}

public PropertyViewModel(Property property)
{
    this.Property = property;
}

// Other code (fields etc)
```

}

This is the view model for the Properties view (containing the grid):

```
public class PropertiesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<PropertyViewModel> PropertyVMs
    {
        get { return this.propertyVMs; }
    }

    public PropertiesViewModel(PropertyPortfolio propertyPortfolio)
    {
        Func<Property, PropertyViewModel> viewModelCreator = model => new PropertyViewModel(model);
        this.propertyVMs = new ObservableViewModelCollection<PropertyViewModel, Property>(propertyPortfolio.Properties, viewModelCreator);
    }

    // Other code (fields etc)
}
```

Comment: Can you show the associated view model code? INPC won't propagate to the *Model* layer unless you have it set up funny.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I've added VM code. I know the problem is the ViewModel collection isn't being updated when the underlying model collection is changed, I just don't know what to do about it...

Comment: Does the PropertyPortfolio raise the PropertyChanged event in its setter?

Comment: Hi @Andrew, yes it fires PropertyChanged. But it seems to break the binding when I call this.PropertyPortfolio = new PropertyPortfolio(/* i.e. loaded from file*/);

Comment: I've got it working in the following way -> The ViewModel for the child collection hooks up to the PropertyChanged event of the PropertyPortfolio. It's not ideal, because I need to load the new PropertyPortfolio from a file and individually assign each child collection. There has to be a cleaner way - perhaps I'm missing something.